# Is it normal for a Properties dialog box "contents" to fluctuate for a very long time?

Tags: usb-drive, file-properties

I have a number of external HDDs. There are two in this example which are the original and its **rsync** duplicate, and I want to check and compare the file structure.

I have used the contextual menu to show **Properties** for a number of directories on each HDD, and it has apparently been calculating the contents for a couple of hours.

Interestingly, the **Contents** quantity and size fluctuates up and down.

For example, one of the volumes will say 18,195 items totalling 10.6GB, then 8,445 items totalling 1.2TB, then 21,237 items totalling 530.2GB, then 4,556 items totalling 1.6GB, and so on, all within 20 seconds.

Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: No, that sounds weird. What filesystems  are you using on the HDDs? What does `du -sch /path/to/directory` (where `/path/to/directory` is one of the directories you want to check) give?

Comment: Ext4 filesystem.

`du -sch` (to a parent directory) gives `1.4T /media/el_gallo_azul/G2/G1/
1.4T total`

Comment: I just took some [screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/TX3pf#0) of the Properties dialog box. I can't find any way to see the time in these **imgur** images - the first screenshot in this series was `Screenshot from 2014-05-25 08:33:19.png` and the last one was `Screenshot from 2014-05-25 08:34:08.png`.